# Running stepper motors continuously for a month

Tags: dc-motor, stepper-motor

I've a small scenario in which it requires a stepper motor ( not require high torque) to run without stopping continuously for long. Stopping for few minutes every month is acceptable. But does that really works or will it stop working by overheating or any other such factors in few hours or even minutes itself.

Missed to mention about the motor. It's a small 5v dc stepper motor.

Comment: Depends on the motor, how you run it, it's environment and conditions. Industrial machines are often running non-stop for much longer periods.

Comment: See https://www.applied-motion.com/news/2015/10/herb-tarlek and http://catalog.orientalmotor.com/Asset/AR-Series-Learn-More.html

Comment: Heat sinking is at the heart of the issue, not only for the motor but also for the H-bridge or other driver IC. Good thermal contact with a large mass of metal with large surface area helps dissipate excess heat before it can damage the devices.

Comment: If it is low torque application, you might be able to just shut off power to the motor and only apply power when you need to step again. Or make a system that reduces the voltage supply when not moving. The reduced voltage will still provide some "holding" torque. This will greatly reduce the heat generated if you are not constantly stepping the motor.

Comment: Consider placing a small fan near the motor and the motor-driver electronics. Keep the delta-temperature LOW.

Answer (score 1):

If you can keep the case temperature of the stepper motor below 30 degC when running continuously you are unlikely to have either coil or magnet problems. Providing the stepper motor does not overheat your only real problem is bearings and gearbox (if you have one).

If you are using cheap low power 5V steppers such as the 28BYJ-48 then the major problem is the bearings (Oilite type sleeve bearing) and gearbox wear. The [datasheet](https://www.petervis.com/Datasheets/28byj48/28byj48-datasheet.gif) provides no information on MTBF, but if you are doing 100's - 1000's of rotations of the output shaft then wear on the motor bearings and the first couple of gears will be significant.

[image]

I'd suggest you may be challenged to get much more than 1000-2000 hr MTBF for this type of unit.

For a more professional stepper motor with sealed ball bearings and no gearbox you might typically get 500k+ hr MTBF, and units such as [this](https://www.moonsindustries.com/series/nema-11-standard-hybrid-stepper-motors-b020102) can get 1M hr MTBF. However these Nema 8 sized units are significantly heavier weighing in at perhaps 0.5 - 0.75 lbs and consume much more power.